# proper IIS 6 configuration for forms authentication

Tags: asp.net, configuration, iis-6, security

I'm using Forms Authentication in my current ASP.NET Web Application (not MVC) and my IIS 6 server is configured with the following options:

in the [directory security tab] -> [Authentication Methods] I have:

- the anonymous access Enabled
- Integrated windows authentication Enabled

Do the above options prevent Forms Authentication from working properly? In other words, what is the proper IIS 6 configuration for Forms Authentication?

**EDIT**

I just made test with the two options above enabled and the Forms Authentication session expired and redirected me to the login page, but all the answers so far advise that [Integrated windows authentication] should be off!

Comment: How long did it take to expire? Have you tried examining the cookies after you login, you can use Firebug (in Firefox) or the IE developer toolbar (hit F12). Have you configured the <authorization> tag to allow (as well as deny) access within the folders that contain your pages?

Comment: 30 mins as i wanted, and yes <authorization> tag is probably configured and both options above enabled!!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a check list for using ASP.NET Forms Authentication on IIS6

**Configure IIS:**

In IIS, Site Properties -> Directory Security -> Authentication and Access Control

- Enable Anonymous Access
- Disable all *Authenticated access methods*

[image]

**Configure Forms Authentication:**

Configure Forms Authentication in your site's `web.config`:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms name="MySite" 
         path="/" 
         loginUrl="~/logon.aspx" 
         protection="All" 
         timeout="30"
         slidingExpiration="true" />
</authentication>
```

Your `name` and `loginUrl` may vary. The `slidigExpiration` attribute is used to keep extending the forms authentication cookie lifetime rather than just kicking the user off of the site after the `timeout` has expired. The `timeout` value is in minutes.

**Configure Session Timeout:**

You need to configure your session state `timeout` to be longer than your Forms Authentication ticket expiry. If you don't do this then an idle session can time out the session but leave the user logged in. Code that expects Session values to be present will throw exceptions because they are gone even though they are still authenticated. The `timeout` value is also in minutes.

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="40" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Because forms authentication does not rely on IIS authentication, you should configure anonymous access for your application in IIS if you intend to use forms authentication in your ASP.NET application.

See here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647070.aspx for more information.

Comment: thanks, so in other words [Integrated windows authentication] should be off when using forms authentications! right

Comment: Yeah. Also make sure the authenticaiton tag mentioned by James is correct. Another thing you need to make sure that you have <authorization> <deny users="?" /> </authorization> . This will deny anynmous users thereby automatically redirecto login page mentioned in the authentication tag.

Answer (score 2):

The anonymous access should be enabled, I don't *think* integrated windows authentication makes a difference but if you're not going to need it then it's best to turn it off. The important thing to remember is to make sure it's turned on in web.config:

```
<authentication mode="Forms" />
```

Here's a basic tutorial that might be useful:

[Overview of Forms Authentication](http://www.asp.net/security/tutorials/an-overview-of-forms-authentication-vb)

Answer (score 2):

Anonymous access -> checked
All other option on the security tab -> unchecked

Note, forms authentication is done by .NET - not by IIS. Also, Windows Authentication MUST be off as well.

Rather [technical explanaitions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647070.aspx#pagexplained0002_aspnetforms) by MS.